# How to troubleshoot OTG cable?

Tags: usb-on-the-go

Because android doesn't handle the broken screen problem very well (frankly, it doesn't handle it at all) I bought OTG cable in hope that I'll be able to connect my mouse to the device.

I connected it to the broken phone (Huawei U8500) and nothing happened. Well, I tried my new android phone Samsung GT-S7710 with Android 4.1.2. However, still no effect. I tried USB flash disk, but that didn't do anything at all.

How can I debug the USB OTG function? To find out what's actually wrong?

Comment: Use adb over Wifi or Bluetooth?

Comment: What is ADB? *Sometimes comment character limit sucks.*

Comment: A tool for developers to communicate between Android and their PC. Unfortunately it needs developer mode to be enabled first which a broken screen might not allow you to do so.

Comment: I had fortunatelly enabled that because I thought I'll have some time to make android apps. I didn't even have time to figure out this broken screen issue in two years.

Comment: Are you sure your device is OTG-A (meaning it provides power to a peripheral device)? You might need a [powered USB-OTG](http://www.amazon.com/Micro-Cable-Power-Galaxy-Samsung/dp/B00CXAC1ZW) adapter instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try OTG Troubleshooter first to check if your setup is working:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homesoft.otgtroubshooter

It will check if your device supports 'usb host mode', if your OTG cable is working and if a mass storage device is found.